# Leaflet map is undefined and initialized at same time

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, leaflet

I'm developing an Ionic app, one of the app's page is a place detail with Leaflet map section.

First time when i enter on a place detail page the map works fine, but when go back and enter on another place detail page an error appears:

> Error: "Map container is already initialized."

I have added part of code to turn off and remove the map but never goes inside because always is undefined but when I try to create it it tells me that it is initialized.

component.st:

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
  if (this.placeMapLeaflet) {
    this.placeMapLeaflet.off();
    this.placeMapLeaflet.remove();
  }
this.placeMapLeaflet = L.map("place_map_leaflet").setView([position.lat, position.lng], this.zoom);
}
```

The problem is that the second time ALWAYS is undefined but it's initialized.

Anybody could help me please ?

Comment: A dirty way would be to remove the map container and recreating it. Then you can initialize the new map

Comment: use ionic lifecycle hook to check if your map is already initialised. use `ionViewWilLEnter(){}` and just update your location data.

Comment: I have `ionViewWilLEnter`to initialize the map, It's always undefined but when I try to create it, tells me that it's initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED with lifecycles:

```
...
ionViewDidEnter() {
  this.placeMapLeaflet = L.map("place_map_leaflet").setView([position.lat, position.lng], this.zoom);
}

ionViewDidLeave() {
  this.placeMapLeaflet.off();
  this.placeMapLeaflet.remove();
}
...
```